# Symfony2 calling a web service

Tags: php, symfony

I am building a API in Symfony2 framework, it turns out I need to make a SOAP call to another webSerice, This is something new to me and am not to sure how to get started, is there a Symfony2 bundle i can use. I googled the SOAP concept and I do understand but I find it hard to get started any tips...?

Thx

Comment: What are exactly difficulties you are stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Bundle:

[BeSimpleSoapBundle](http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/)

Answer (score 0):

SoapBundle https://packagist.org/packages/besimple/soap-bundle

Or RestBundle maybe ? https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle